# Warning about NEXTAUTH_URL in Development Console

Tags: typescript, next.js, environment-variables, pnpm

I am developing a `Next.js` web application with `next-auth` for authentication, and I've encountered a warning message in my development console when running the application. The message looks like this:

```
 Reload env: .env.local
 ○ compiling /signin/page ...
 ✓ Compiled /signin/page in 5s (602 modules)
 ✓ Compiled /api/auth/[...nextauth]/route in 2.1s (975 modules)
[next-auth][warn][NEXTAUTH_URL]
```

I am using Next.js version `13.5.2` along with `pnpm`, and I have set up my environment variables in my `.env` file as follows:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=<CLIENT_ID>
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=<CLIENT_SECRET>
AUTH_SECRET=<AUTH_SECRET>
```

I would like to understand the meaning of this warning message and whether I need to address it in my Next.js application. How can I resolve this warning?

I followed the setup instructions in the `next-auth` documentation, including configuring my `.env` file with necessary environment variables such as `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID`, `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET`, and `AUTH_SECRET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NEXTAUTH_URL` is the canonical url of your Next.js app.

> On Vercel deployments, we will read the VERCEL_URL environment variable, so you won't need to define NEXTAUTH_URL.
>
> https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#nextauth_url

Since you are running the application in your local, you need to set it in `.env.local`

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Note: if your application url is different, please update the url as required.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time, and I understand now what happened. The warning is gone after I set that in my local env file. The problem is solved now.